# Regular Expression Finding A Backslash, Not Special Character

Tags: regex

How do i search for the backslash character in special characters? For example, If I have a string '\ba \wa', my regex '\\.a' is not going to find either group because it treats '\b' and '\w' as single special characters.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask.  Your regex matches both \ba and \wa.

Comment: The language you're using may require you to also escape backslashes in any literal string. Thus you would have to write `"\\\\"` to produce a string that contains two consecutive backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the backslash:

```
'\\.a'
```

The escape sequence `\\` is the backslash character.

Comment: The '\b' is interpreted as a word boundary. How do I get the regex to treat it as normal characters?

Answer (score 0):

This one will work

```
 /\\.*a/
```

See the refiddle [Regex fiddle link](http://refiddle.co/2ema)

Answer (score 0):

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="\\ba \\wa";
    System.out.println(input.matches("\\\\ba \\\\wa"));
}
```

}

Produces True.